# Uploadify formData not coming over

Tags: uploadify

I'm trying to implement Uploadify into a classic ASP application. The values I'm passing in the settings `formData` are not available in `upload.asp`. I've tried putting `formData` in it's own option field and that isn't working either.

Funny part is that I can 'see' it in Fiddler...so I'm not sure what the heck is going on.

Below is my uploadify code. In upload.asp a call to `request.form("sellerid")` is blank.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
      'method'        : 'post',
      'swf'           : 'uploadify.swf',
      'uploader'      : 'upload.asp',
      'onUploadStart' : function(file) {          
         $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "formData",  
           { "sellerid" : "999", "sellerloginid" : "joeseller" }
         );
       }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: try changing `"sellerid" : "999"` to `"sellerid" : 999, `

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try placing a debugger in `onUploadStart` and see whether it is hitting or not

Comment: If it is in fidder then the problem is likely on the receiving end. What does your receiving code look like? I have no problem extracting formData values on the server from uploadify (we pass up a user selected value for each file).